# Calculating matrix sqaure determinant

Tags: java, loops, math, matrix, multiplication

I'm trying to code a function that calculates a sqaured-matrix determinant (of which all numbers of the diagonal are multiplied) for self coding. I got the main idea but I can't get the right result because of some calculation error. this is the code I wrote:

```
public static int det(int[][] matrix, int n) {
     int i,j, k, det=1;
     for (i=0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
         for (j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
             if (i<j)
                 if(matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                     //isTriangle = true;
                     det *= matrix[i][i];
                 }
             if (i>j)
                 if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                     //isTriangle = true;
                     det *= matrix[i][i];
                 } 
         }
     }
     return det;
 }
```

After I run this function I get results that don't include the final number (matrix[n][n]) because it wasn't multiplied for some reason. Next thing I tried to set a for loop that will multiply all the members of the diagonal (det *= matrix[k][k]) outside the two loops but then I got very high numbers as a result. What am I doing wrong with the math here?

Comment: This calculates product of all a_i ^ n_i where a_ is the element on the diagonal in i-th row, and n_i is number of elements in i-th row that are equal to zero (excluding the one on the diagonal, if it's zero as well).

Comment: Thanks. do you have any idea what calculation should be made here?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not correct. It should look like this:

1. Make the input matrix triangular using Gaussian elimination.
2. Multiply all numbers on the diagonal(that is, find a product of `matrix[i][i]` for all `i`).

You cannot skip the first step.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a recursion.

Given the n by n matrix M, we create W(i,j) by striking out column i and row j of M.

So for the 3 x 3 matrix:

```
 1 2 3  
 4 5 6  
 7 8 9  

W(0,0) =  
 5 6  
 8 9  

W(1,0) =  
 4 6  
 7 9
```

etc.

Now you can expand around any row or column.

Additionally you need to alternate + and -; for a 3 x 3 Matrix it would look like this:
 + - +
 - + -
 + - +

So expanding around column 2, we get:

```
+ 3 * det  
  4 5  
  7 8  

- 6 * det   
  1 2  
  7 8   

+ 9 * det
  1 2
  4 5
```

Or

```
  -1^(2+0) * M(2,0)*det(W(2,0))
+ -1^(2+1) * M(2,1)*det(W(2,1))
+ -1^(2+2) * M(2,2)*det(W(2,2))
```

I am deliberately working from example because the formula looks a bit scary:

```
det(M) = sum(i=0 to N-1){ -1 ^ i * M(i,0) * det(W(i,0)) }
```

Note that in this formula that we are expanding around the first row (instead of the third column as before)